# Folder structure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, directory

Still on my early days of learning ASP.NET. Just wondering is there a best practice way to structure your folders in ASP.NET? i know the convention or standards in an MVC project. is there anything similar in pure ASP.NET?

If there are no standards. please kindly let me see how you(experienced asp.net gurus) structure your projects with explanations.

Thanks

Comment: i saw this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but it wasnt too clear and there was no diagram or sample snapshot and therefore wasnt too easy for new comers to understand

Comment: A lot of my WebForms projects I try to keep as lightweight as possible, so the only code in the WebForm project would be the code-behind (.aspx.cs or .aspx.vb).  All business logic I would put in a separate project, same for data access logic.  As the project gets bigger you'll get even more projects, but best practice is to keep the UI layer thin and have functionality in a separate project in stand-alone code files which are decoupled (look up loose coupling and separation of concerns) from the UI.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned "pure ASP.NET", so it conveys that you want to put your business such as data access, business rules, validation, etc. in the code behind of your web forms. Is it right?

Comment: @AbbasAmiri not exactly. by "pure ASP.NET" i mean "NOT ASP.NET MVC"...so i'm open to knowing where to keep stuffs including data access, business rules,validations etc

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you will see

- /App_Data (Standard)
- /App_Start (Standard - New)
- /App_Themes (Standard - Old)
- /Content (Standard - New)
- /Controls
- /Images
- /Scripts
- /MasterPages

The rest are personal preferences.

However, we normally keep authorized aspx pages in separate folder, so that we can use web.config to restrict access.

Here is DotNetNuke 06.02.03's folder structure.

[image]

Comment: thanks...but i'm not sure i know exactly what DotNetNuke is. however, i see a controls folder above.is that where all controls goto?using this folder structure?

Comment: [DotNetNuke](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/) is one of the popular open source .Net application which uses ASP.Net Web Form. Yes, user controls are stored in controls folder; however, server controls are stored in Class Libraries. You can download the current version, and see it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, developers normally categorize their materials in the folders that its name conveys the content; for example, they, normally, put all of CSSs, images and Java Scripts in Assets folder or if they have more than one Master Page, they put them in MastePages folder.

You should distinct your Web-Forms based on the business that they're related to, for instance, all of forms about users should put in Account folder.

I have to mention that in enterprise level applications that use modularity, MVP or MVC design pattern, Dependency Injection, etc. The distinction is based on Separation Of Concern.

All in all, it's important that your folder's name conveys the materials in it.